# Reusing the xamarin forms renderer in .net maui

Tags: maui, custom-renderer

I am working on migrating xamarin forms application to .net maui.

as part of migration i am working on reusing the xamarin forms renderers in .net maui with "Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" package.

when i am registering the renderer in MauiProgram.cs using ConfigureMauiHandlers getting error

below is my code in MauiProgram.cs to ConfigureMauiHandlers. Getting error for

```cs
typeof(CardReaderViewRenderer) as this is the iOS implementation of Renderer.
```

Error : The type or namespace name 'CardReaderViewRenderer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```cs
 var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .UseMauiCompatibility()
                .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
                {
                    handlers.AddCompatibilityRenderer(typeof(CardReaderView), typeof(CardReaderViewRenderer));

#if __IOS__

                    
#elif __ANDROID__
#endif
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error show, that may due to the loss of the assembly reference so the CardReaderViewRenderer cannot be found.

You could try code like this:

```
.ConfigureMauiHandlers((handlers) =>
        {
#if ANDROID
            handlers.AddHandler(typeof(CardReaderView),typeof(XamarinCustomRenderer.Droid.Renderers.CardReaderViewRenderer));
#elif IOS
            handlers.AddHandler(typeof(CardReaderView), typeof(XamarinCustomRenderer.iOS.Renderers.CardReaderViewRenderer));
#endif
        });
```

For more info, you could refer to [Use custom renderers in .NET MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/custom-renderers?view=net-maui-7.0) and [sample code](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/tree/main/Upgrading/CustomRenderer)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried your suggestion. But still getting errors. "XamarinCustomRenderer" is the project name from above link "Use custom renderers in .NET MAUI ".

Comment: So what's the namespace for CardReaderViewRenderer? You just migrate this file from Xamarin Forms project

Comment: naemspace for CardReaderViewRenderer is LibraryTestAppMaui.iOS. CardReaderViewRenderer.   I have migrated xamarin project to .net maui. My project is not a single project. Having forms, iOS, android projects.